# Microsoft Access 2010 Max query on Count results

Tags: ms-access

I need my access db i'm trying to use the Max function on the results of a Count function of a field
i couldn't find any way of doing it - not through the user interface and not through SQL query.

**This is my screen:**
[image]

in the  screen i have the count function working properly

how can i run the Max function on the Count function results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "run the Max function on the Count function results" requires that you "roll up" your count results to a higher level of aggregation. Save your existing query as `HallCounts` and then create a new query that does something like

```
SELECT Country_Id, Max(CountOfHall_Id) AS MaxHallCount 
FROM HallCounts 
GROUP BY Country_Id;
```

Or, to select just the row(s) with the highest count, try something like this

```
SELECT * FROM HallCounts 
WHERE CountOfHall_ID = (SELECT MAX(CountOfHall_ID) FROM HallCounts);
```

Comment: this return the maximum value of count in each row.
i need it to return only the row with the maximum count...

Answer (score 1):

I would use the TOP 1 SQL and DESC function. Or in the designer view it's "Return".

For example:

```
SELECT TOP 1 the_column_to_display
FROM the_table
ORDER BY Count(the_column_to_count) DESC;
```